# Is it possible to store a resource in memcache?

Tags: ruby, resources, memcached

I have not tried yet, as I would rather not spend time setting up memcached if this is not going to work...

I am using Ruby. Is is possible to store a resource, such as an FTP connection, in memcache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store anything that is serializable in memcache.  An ftp connection is likely not serializable, however.